# Tab system 3 by 3 items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to create a dictionary with different word. I would like to display definitions under words. 3 by 3 in desktop, 2 by 2 in tablet and 1 by 1 in mobile (accordion system).

I added a `data-link` attribute in each li of my list and a `data-content` attribute in each div.

I try to match each `data-link` with each `data-content`

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#" data-link="0">Word 01</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-link="1">Word 02</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-link="2">Word 03</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-link="3">Word 04</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-link="4">Word 05</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-link="5">Word 06</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div data-content="0">Definition of word 01</div>
    <div data-content="1">Definition of word 02</div>
    <div data-content="2">Definition of word 03</div>
    <div data-content="3">Definition of word 04</div>
    <div data-content="4">Definition of word 05</div>
    <div data-content="5">Definition of word 06</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/qbh79xoy/27/

**Desktop version :**

[image]

**Mobile version :**

[image: Liste 2]

This list will be generated by Wordpress. At the begining we will get 50 words and after 100. Definitions will be automatically injected with PHP by Wordpress in the HTML page. So the list must be dynamic. Can I have some help please ?

Comment: Your question is really unclear partly because your English is not very good. Could you create an image so it would be more clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, I'm sorry for my bad english, I updated my post with a picture.

Comment: So you want definitions of 1,2 & 3 to be displayed in same space, and 4,5 & 6 in same space, etc?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, exactly ! But I would like that each li are in the same list, not separated. Because in mobile version each definition will be under each word.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but I gave it a go.

I started by restructuring the HTML, into a more appropriate format. Then I added the CSS, which on devices larger than 544px will only show the definition with the class active.

Then using a simple on click in jQuery, it switches between the definitions!

```js
$('.section .word').on('click', function(){
  $(this).closest('.container').siblings().andSelf().find('.section .definition').removeClass('active');
  $(this).next('.definition').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
hr {
  display: none;
}

.container {}

.container .section {}

.container .section .word {}

.container .section .definition {
  display: none;
}

.container .section .definition.active {
  display: block;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 544px) {
  hr {
    display: block;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .container .section {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .container .section .word {}
  .container .section .definition {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p class="word">One</p>
    <p class="definition active">Text text one</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <p class="word">Two</p>
    <p class="definition">Text text two</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <p class="word">Three</p>
    <p class="definition">Text text three</p>
  </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <p class="word">Four</p>
    <p class="definition">Text text four</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <p class="word">Five</p>
    <p class="definition">Text text five</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section">
    <p class="word">Six</p>
    <p class="definition">Text text six</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the time you past on it. In fact I try to display one definition at a time. And in mobile version that the definitions be display like in an accordion.

Comment: Yes, it works exactly as your images do. Just increase/decrease your browser window :)

Comment: I've updated my answer. That should be the solution you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah in mobile this is good, but for the desktop version no because I must display one word at a time.

Comment: Okay, well that is again a much simpler solution. I have updated the code for you

Comment: Great !! And that's run without flexbox ? (for IE9+). This is just a question of css now ?

Comment: I don't have the time to do it without flexbox, sorry. But if this answer helped I'd appreciate an upvote :)

Comment: Don't worry. That's cool from your part. I voted. Thank you again !